# How do I host my Mvc web app using plesk panel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting, web-hosting

I have registerd my own domain name and web hosting space too on `parallels`

thay are having there `plesk control panel`.

I know that for html pages I need to copy my all pages into `httpdoc` folder

```
But what about by MVC WEBSITE?

HOW DO I HOST IT?
```

CAN ANYONE HELP ME?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to copy the whole mvc project into **httpdocs** folder to view it online.

You are getting the **500 - internal server error** may be because the `mvc version` differs in the server(`i mean may be you are using mvc v4 and the server has mvc v2`).

So just contact your hosting provider, i am sure you will get a good solution.

Comment: Hi I contacted my web hosting provider they said its issue from your side.

Comment: Then, please post full error message that you get. Maybe we can help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the previous answers;

You need to ensure you are copying your websites 'bin' folder.
You may also need to ensure that the MVC assemblies are in it.

When you installed MVC on your local machine several assemblies are registered with the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).
It may be that your host does not have all the required ASP.NET MVC assemblies installed; if not then you will see a configuration error.

As these assemblies are registered in the GAC, the bin folder will not contain them by default.

Make sure your project explicitly references the following DLLs and make sure the **Copy Local** property is true.

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Rebuild your project and check the bin folder. These files should now be present. 
Upload the contents of this folder to your host.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an MVC5 app using ASP .NET 4.5. To solve it, I used the Visual Studio publish Tool (Image1) right clicking in the solution explorer. [image]

Then the Web App was published successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you copy the whole project into httpdoc , then u must enable wildcard ASP .NET mapping for the website , ask your hosting system admin , usually they can do that

Comment: getting error : 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (from Visual Studio) using the Publish utility to actually upload your website.  Plesk Hosting offers support for Web Deploy which is probably your best option, or alternatively you can pick FTP.  When you use Visual Studio's publish, it *should* (I think) include the dependencies you have (in case you had anything in the GAC)

Answer (score 0):

Select the following assemblies:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

In the Properties window, set Copy Local to True.

then upload bin folder in mvc to the server. this may fix the issue